# SQL Azure not recognizing my clustered Index

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, clustered-index

I get the following error when I try to insert a row into a SQL Azure table.

> Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of
>   SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again.

My problem is I do have a clustered index on that table.  I used SQL Azure MW to generate the Azure SQL Script.

Here's what I'm using:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tblPasswordReset]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[tblPasswordReset]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tblPasswordReset]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblPasswordReset](
    [PasswordResetID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PasswordResetGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [MemberID] [int] NULL,
    [RequestDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblPasswordReset] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PasswordResetID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
END
GO
```

Why doesn't SQL Azure recognize my clustered Key? Is my script wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script only creates the table if it did not exist yet.  Perhaps there still is an old version of the table without a clustered index?  You can check with:

```
select * from sys.indexes where object_id = object_id('tblPasswordReset')
```

If the table exists without the clustered index, you can add one like:

```
alter table tblPasswordReset add constraint
    PK_tblPasswordReset primary key clustered
```

As far as I can see, your statement does conform to the [Azure create table spec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn305849.aspx).

Comment: When I run that select script I do get a result for PK_tblPasswordReset type_desc = CLUSTERED.

This is weird...

Comment: Is there a trigger on the table?  `select * from sys.triggers where object_id = object_id('tblPasswordReset')`  The trigger might do an insert on an unclustered table.

Comment: I've just run your exact script on a SQL Azure DB and it ran fine.  I suspect that the issue lies with something else in your DB conflicting with this script.  Maybe a previously created version of the table?

Comment: @Andomar  This table doesn't have any triggers

Comment: @knightpfhor I dont have any problems running the script and creating the table.  It's when I try to insert a row in the DB through .NET that I get the error.  I'm thinking that I have some other version of the table, but I don't know how to check for that.

Comment: It's a long shot, but maybe your code is not pointing at the DB you think it is.  Just to experiment, try dropping the table and running the code, you should get a completely different error.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful if you're using SSIS.  I ran into this same problem, myself, but was using SSIS instead of manually inserting the data.  By default SSIS will drop and recreate the table, so even though I had it properly defined with a clustered index, my SSIS script failed.  On the "Edit Mappings" step in the SSIS wizard you can manually define the table creation script.  I just deleted the table gen script there and my import worked.

(I'd leave this as a comment but my post count is too anemic)