# Clustered Index Error in Azure for a Table that Has a Clustered Index

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I am running this command on SQL Azure.

```
DELETE FROM dbo.Users
```

I am getting this error.

> Msg 40054, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again.

I then try to create a clustered index.

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX Idx_Users ON dbo.Users(Id);
```

I get this error.

> Msg 1902, Level 16, State 3, Line 4
>   Cannot create more than one clustered index on table 'dbo.Users'. Drop the  existing clustered index 'PK_dbo.Users' before creating another.

Do I or do I NOT have a clustered index?

Comment: Did you try dropping then creating index?

Comment: Can you truncate the table instead of deleting everything in it?

Comment: I'm able to truncate but had to remove foreign key constraints to make it happen. I'd like to avoid doing this next time.

Comment: Dropping an index is not supported in SQL Azure V11, upgrade the server to V12 which has many features that includes supporting the heap.

Comment: You can run sp_help [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933429%28v=sql.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for the for the table to figure out what indexes and constraints exist. Do you see the same error when you insert data? Also do you constraints cascade the delete operation? Maybe you have a missing index on one of the other tables.

Comment: And also check for triggers on the table that might trigger an insert, update or delete on another table that might not have an clustered index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue where I was unable to delete records from a table.

After reading this post, [SQL Azure not recognizing my clustered Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224043/sql-azure-not-recognizing-my-clustered-index), paired with your post I checked the dependencies through MSSMS on my `Security_User` table; a 0-n relationship table, `Security_UserHistory`, had a FK-reference to this table. This reference was not indexed and (strangely enough) triggered the error in question.

After applying a CLUSTERED INDEX to the FK-table `Security_UserHistory` referencing the PK-table `Security_User`  the problem was solved.

[image]

I wish Microsoft would add some clarity in the error message, as it indicates the problem lies with the table you are deleting the rows from.

Comment: Are you saying that I should manually create an index for every FK reference on my tables?

Comment: I am saying, that for my case the error was a result of a missing clustered index on a FK-table. There was an associated trigger that would write to Security_UserHistory - maybe that had something to do with it as well. However, just removing the trigger did not fix the issue, why I did not think to mention it before.